# SQL - ORDER BY not returning results

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I'm trying to solve this challenge (NOT ASKING FOR THE FINAL SOLUTION)!
[Problem Link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-5)

First step: I wanted to return the list of city, length(city) sorted by length to use than `ROWNUMBER = 1`.

To select city with shortest name:

My code is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT city, LENGTH(city) FROM station ORDER BY LENGTH(city) ASC;
```

I was expecting the result to be sorted by LENGTH but it is sorted by city. If I change to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT city, LENGTH(city) FROM station ORDER BY city DESC;
```

It is still sorted by city in ASC order.

What am I doing wrong? Or it is a problem with the page because even `SELECT city FROM station ORDER by city DESC;` does not work.

Thanks.

Comment: Your first query should do just fine. (However, I'd do `SELECT DISTINCT city, LENGTH(city) as len FROM station ORDER BY len ASC;`)

Comment: Looks like a problem with the page to me. There is nothing wrong with the fist query.

Comment: I would still be inclined to use Gordon's version though, when using `DISTINCT` the `LEN` function will be called on every row, then duplicates removed, whereas when using `GROUP BY` the duplicates are removed first and then the `LEN` function is called on the remaining records. For something with very low overhead like `LEN` and depending on the number of dupes this is a fairly trivial optimisation, but for other functions (specifically user defined) or for data where there are a large number of duplicates this could be more significant.

Answer (score 0):

This may depend on the database, but it would seem that `distinct` may be processed after the `order by`.  Just use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT city, LENGTH(city)
FROM station
GROUP BY city
ORDER BY LENGTH(city) ASC;
```

Comment: I swear it's not my downvote, but this won't run in most RDBMS because you are grouping by one column and not using an aggregation function in the other....so I'm not really sure about the upvote...

Comment: Aggregate functions are not required when GROUP BY. However, DISTINCT is supposed to be processed (logically) before ORDER BY, and even if it isn't - it shouldn't matter. The original query should return the expected result.

Comment: @Lamak Most DBMS I know of are smart enough to recognise that `LEN(City)` is functionally dependant on `City` and would therefore allow it

Comment: @Lamak . . . Of course this will work in any database.  You can run functions on the `group by` keys.  The `GROUP BY` key is `city`; `LENGTH()` just takes it as an argument.

Comment: @jarlh . . . Note the first sentence.  Whatever database the OP is using does not seem to be adhering to that convention (or is it a standard).

Comment: @GordonLinoff You are right, didn't even notice it was function on the first column. But, well, as I said, not my downvote

Comment: @Lamak . . . I wouldn't expect an anonymous downvote from you.